# Google Calendar Auto Timezone

Tags: php, javascript, timezone, google-calendar-api, gmt

I'm doing a simple website for a client that includes a Google Calendar for displaying of upcoming events. The problem here is that I can't figure out how to get the timezone for the calendar to auto-update on a per-user basis, as it just won't due for someone to come look at the calendar and see their local event starting at 4:00 (Chicago time), when in reality it starts at 2:00 (Seattle time).

The nearest I can figure, I need to get the GMT timezone and convert that to a city/state string, which can then be spliced into the iframe src where gCal has the ctz variable.

I'm using PHP and heavy JavaScript+jQuery. If you have any suggestions for a faster alternative, I'd be grateful, as the code for converting GMT to city/state could be lengthy.... and this isn't a paid project. xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you can set your calendar to 'calendar zone' and then it will update appropriately. you can also display 2 time zones. see this link for more details:
http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=83117